# Apache-cxf JAXRSClient custom Dateformat

Tags: java, apache, jax-rs, cxf, simpledateformat

I'm using apache-cxf-jaxrs with Proxy-Pattern. But i'm not able to change the dateformat for the Query Parameter.

There is my interface:

```
@Path("/api/data")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface DataService {

 @GET
 @Path("/")
 List<DataDto> getData(@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd") @QueryParam("from") Date from);
}
```

Client is initialized about:

```
JacksonJsonProvider jsp = new JacksonJsonProvider();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"));       
jsp.setMapper(objectMapper);
DataService  serviceClient = (DataService) 
JAXRSClientFactory.create(baseUrl, serviceClass, Arrays.asList(jsp));
```

Calling following code causes a java.time.format.DateTimeParseException in my backend, because the Date ist formatted as DateFormat.DEFAULT and not in "yyyyMMdd".

```
  serviceClient.getData(new Date());
```

My ObjectMapper with the SimpleDateFormatter is never used. I did forgot something, but i have no clue what is it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I got it. 
I have to register a new ParamConverterProvider for the dateformat.

```
JAXRSClientFactory.create(baseUrl, serviceClass, Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider(), new MyCustomDataParamConverter()));
```